# Sending arguments via Soap in Node.js using node-soap

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, soap

I am just getting started with NodeJS and I digging into talking to a SOAP service using [milewise's node-soap](https://github.com/milewise/node-soap#readme). I am using a basic email address validation SOAP API as my test case.

I don't seem to understand the correct way to format my arguments lists.

My SOAP client code:

```
    var url = "http://www.restfulwebservices.net/wcf/EmailValidationService.svc?wsdl";
soap.createClient(url, function(err, client){
    console.log(client.describe().EmailValidationService.BasicHttpBinding_IEmailValidationService.Validate);
    client.Validate({result:"my@emailaddress.com"}, function(err, result){
            console.log(result);
    });
});
```

The client.describe() command tells me how the API would like its input formatted, and how it will return its output.  This is what is says:

`{ input: { 'request[]': 'xs:string' },
  output: { 'ValidateResult[]': 'xs:boolean' } }`

However when I send the arguments as an object: `{request:"my@emailaddress.com"}`

I feel like my problems lies in how I am defining the arguments object...what do the brackets in `request[]` mean?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It should work, if you add namespace on request argument.
This is a sample code.

```
var soap = require('soap');

var url = "http://www.restfulwebservices.net/wcf/EmailValidationService.svc?wsdl";

var args = {"tns:request":"my@emailaddress.com"};

soap.createClient(url, function(err, client){
    client.EmailValidationService.BasicHttpBinding_IEmailValidationService.Validate(args, function(err, result){
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(result);
    });
});
```

However, it returns "Access is denied".

I use soapUI to test this web service, it returns the same result.

I try another web service, and it works.

```
var soap = require('soap');

var url = "http://www.restfulwebservices.net/wcf/StockQuoteService.svc?wsdl";

var args = {"tns:request":"GOOG"};

soap.createClient(url, function(err, client){

    client.StockQuoteService.BasicHttpBinding_IStockQuoteService.GetStockQuote(args, function(err, result){
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(result);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`ValidateResult` takes an array request. That is what `request[]` means. If it was an object it should just be request. Therefore, if you try args as follows, it may work:

```
var args = {request[]: ["my@emailadress.com", "another email adress if you
want"]};
```

Answer (score -1):

```
I have similar situation where i have accountId[] , i need to pass multiple accountID, when i pass like "tns:accountId[]": [2321,2345325], it failing saying incorrect request parameter, it comes as <tns:accountId[]>2321</tns:accountId[]>
<tns:accountId[]>2345325</tns:accountId[]>.

I need to get <tns:accountId>2321</tns:accountId>
<tns:accountId>2345325</tns:accountId>. When i tried removing "[]", it comes as <accountId> only and  it is failing. Can someone please help me?
```