# Is there schema validation in node-soap?

Tags: xml, node.js, web-services, soap, wsdl

We're using [node-soap](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap) to create a SOAP client to interact with an external web service.

Although we include the wsdls which contain a full schema, no validation is being done on the requests. Unfortunately the external server's error message when the validation fails is not helpful at all.

Is there a way to validate the request against the schema defined in the wsdl using node-soap? Or do I have to use something like [libxml-xsd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/libxml-xsd) and do the validation myself?

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16006988/sending-arguments-via-soap-in-node-js-using-node-soap), the client has a "Validate" method, but it doesn't appear to in the latest version.

Comment: The client.Validate() function you're seeing in that question is from the service which is an email validation service. In other words, client.Validate() sends a SOAP request to the service to validate an email. It doesn't validate the request itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appears to be an option called 'returnFault' used during client creation to validate requests against a wsdl. I've tracked it to wsdl.js, and it does seem to be used to validate against the wsdl. However, I can't get it to throw an error for invalid options, and like you, my server error is less than helpful.

Unfortunately, I think this is a bug in node-soap.

Comment: I made the returnFault option true but no error was thrown for invalid request